# ASP.Net WebApi: How to load additional controllers at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

in my Asp.Net MVC 4 WebApi application I want to load  additional WebApiControllers dynamically at a later time (after the WebApi initialization), which are in separate assemblies. Furthermore I want to add routes for those controllers at runtime.

I am wonder, if this is possible to do.

My goal is to build a web-app, where I can upload controllers (compiled assemblies) and the controllers will be automatically hosted within this application.

I've already tried to achieve that by implementing my own AssemblyResolver class, but (as far as I have seen), the AssemblyResolver is loaded once at initialization phase.

May be there is an option to "re-load" all controllers.

Any help will be appreciated!

Marius

Comment: A former colleague of mine got something almost identical to this working in our system. I know he ended up using [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to manage dynamic assembly loading, but I don't remember the specifics. I sent him a link to this post, perhaps he'll get back to you. In the meantime, you can try coming up with a solution yourself with MEF.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=898  have you seen this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Web API Dependency Resolver:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DependencyResolver = new MyDependencyResolver();
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ConfigureApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        // ...
    }
}
```

[Using the Web API Dependency Resolver](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers.

I figured it out, it is not possible to do that, since all of the controllers are loaded once and are cached all over the time.

See HttpControllerTypeCache in [DefaultHttpControllerSelector](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0c48eef64d80#src%2fSystem.Web.Http%2fDispatcher%2fDefaultHttpControllerSelector.cs) method InitializeControllerInfoCache(...).

In oder to do a type-cache refresh, I have to implement a custom HttpControllerSelector.

Answer (score 2):

MEF is the way to go. You will need to create your own controller factory to replace the default controller factory. Take a look at this link <strike>http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104</strike>

*Edit: dead link, see Wayback*
https://web.archive.org/web/20130619191423/http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104

Answer (score 0):

I think you need take a look at this  http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx as a start point.

Answer (score 0):

What about if in Global.asax you loaded all assemblies in a specific folder and then looked for a class that implements a specific interface, for example

void RegisterControllers(RouteCollection routes);

Create an instance and then pass in your route collection.  This would then register the additional routes during the website startup.

Comment: Hi Peter, I want to dynamically loading additional WebAPi controllers at a later time (when the web site is already running). I know how to load controllers in global.asax, but this happens just one time - on start-up.

Comment: Doesn't IIS restart the web app anyway when you alter the contents of the binaries folder?