# Compiling a .Net Web Application like a .Net Website project

Tags: .net, code-behind

Ive been asked to make some changes to a .Net Web Application. However, the client seems to have "Lost" the precompiled source code.

Traditionally, a .Net Web Application Project must have the codebehind compiled into a DLL, whereas a .Net Website Project can compile itself into runnable code when its requested by the browser.

Since I dont have the original source code to this project, I cant add new code to the DLL. I created a new ascx.cs codebehind file, placed it in the same directory as the ascx page and referenced it from the ascx page.

However, the ascx page can not detect this file. I suspect its because the codebehind is not part of the dll. Is there a way to force the web application to compile the codebehind when its requested by the browser just like a .Net Website project.

I know this is terrible practice and most will say dont do it, so Im also open to alternative suggestions as well. I would like to tell the client I cant work without the source, but its not my decision.

Comment: try some tool like ILSpy or .Net reflector to get source code back from DLLs.

Comment: I used, dotPeek, however it was only able to give me about 80% of the code intact, the other 20% had compiler generated artifacts as a result of temp variables and unicode chars it couldnt translate.

Comment: well those are mostly generic classes, variables, delegates etc. that you have to do yourself.

Comment: Decompiling is the way to go.  80% is better than having to completely rewrite & reverse engineer the app.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580243/asp-net-webapi-how-to-load-additional-controllers-at-runtime for possible voodoo magic solution

Comment: lmao, reverse engineering is the last thing I wanted to do, Originally I only needed to change 3 lines of code in the dll to make the necessary change. But my supervisor just saw your comments and decided thats gonna be my project for the rest of the week :P